# Metric space Cat. I and Cat. 2

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

In Munroe1956, *Introduction to Measure Theory and Integration*, I found this exercise

> Let $\Omega$ be a complete metric space. Let $\mu^*(E)=0$ if $E$ is of Cat. I, $\mu^*(E)=1$ if E is of Cat. II. Show that $\mu^*$ is an outer measure, and determine the class of measurable sets.

Are the *Cat. I* and *Cat. II* connected with the [CAT(k) space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAT(k)_space) concept or they mean something else?

Comment: A Cat I set is a countable union of nowhere dense sets. A Cat II set is one which is not of Cat I.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Baire category has nothing to do with $\text{CAT}(k)$.

Baire's terminology Category I , Category II is from 1899.

Notation $\text{CAT}(k)$ is from 1987.

Alternate terminology from Bourbaki: nowhere dense = rare, Category I = meagre, Category II = nonmeagre.